# Keras: why does entire epoch take longer time when it shows all batches are complete?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to train a VGG16 model and have 4k training samples and 2k validation samples.

[image]

In the above image, even though the first 134 batches get completed very fast, the last batch waits for a long time and finishes after ~8mins, which I think is taking too long. Is there something wrong that I am doing? Using the following to start the training process.

`model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])`

`model.fit_generator(train_generator, samples_per_epoch=4320, epochs=50, validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=2880)`

Answer (score 8):

When an epoch finishes, as you are providing validation data, Keras has to evaluate your model on the evaluation set, that's what takes 8 minutes in your case.

Comment: Thanks for answering, is it normal for it to take 2 mins for training over 4320 samples and validation over 2.8k samples taking 6 mins? Training does both backward and forward prop, where as validation should do forward prop only.

Comment: @ssahu Looking at your log one epoch takes 8 minutes, evaluation on validation data is not part of those 8 minutes.

Comment: I was passing ```nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples``` instead of ```nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples // batch_size``` - number of batches for validation in ```model.fit_generator```, thanks for the insight, it helped me find the issue.